# Unable to get the properties of touchstart event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, jquery-events

When I try to implement the below code:

```
$('.touchelement').bind({'touchstart':function(e){
    console.info(e.touches.item(0));
}});
```

It shows the output as undefined. Not only in `touchstart`, but for every other event like (`touchmove`, `touchend`) it shows the same result.

Is there is any alternate way to bind the `touchstart` event using jQuery.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

jQuery does some processing on event objects to make them consistent across browsers, but it doesn't know about the `touches` array so this isn't copied to the new event object. So, you need to access it through the original event object which is `event.originalEvent`.

```
$('.touchelement').bind({'touchstart':function(e){
  console.info(e.originalEvent.touches[0]);
}});
```

Comment: @Richard M great!!!!!!!! blimey thanks for teaching me the ugly truth about jQuerys tantarum!! i was frustrated 8 hours and half in finding where the touches was going . really you sir are a life savor!

Answer (score 0):

Should it not look more like this?

```
$('.touchelement').bind('touchstart', function(e){
  console.info(e.touches);
});
```

Comment: Sorry, gotta ask. Are you testing in a browser that supports the `touchstart` event? You can test for support of touch events using `$.support.touch`, which returns a boolean value.